# Solution Explorer not showing files after Get Latest

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs

I am working with another dev and we're using TFS for source control. When he checks in a file or folder, I can see them with Source Control Explorer. I can do a Get Latest, and I can see that the file or folder is pulled down to my local file system.

However, if I flip over to my Solution Explorer, his new files or folders aren't appearing. I have clicked refresh, I have done a Get Latest from Solution Explorer, I have done a Get Specific Version from Solution Explorer.

Is there something I'm supposed to do to have them show up? Do I need to do an Add Existing Item every time he adds something to source control?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Is the other dev adding the files to the project (csproj /vbpoj) when he checks them in or just adding them to source control? If so is he also checking in the updated project file as well as the new source files?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Adding files to source control is not the same thing with adding files to a project.

You are supposed to see the files on source control also.

To be able to see the files on solution explorer you need to add files to existing project by "Add Existing Item" option.